# HTTP Fetching failing on PHP OpenID

Tags: php, openid

I have dropped a php v5 openid library into a site and ran detect.php which fails on 'HTTP Fetching' (report at the end of this message). The discovery.php also fails. The server is running on HTTPS and has all the needed libraries added so should just work - as it has on other servers I have implemented it on.

Any attempt to run the consumer/try_auth.php fails with an error 'not a valid OpenID' which apparently is being caused by the failure to http fetch.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

> **OpenID Library Support Report**
>
> This script checks your PHP installation to determine if you are set
>   up to use the JanRain PHP OpenID library.
>
> **Setup Incomplete**
>
> Your system needs a few changes before it will be ready to run the
>   OpenID library.
>
> **Math support**
>
> Your PHP installation has gmp support. Good.
>
> Cryptographic-quality randomness source
>
> Using (insecure) pseudorandom number source, because
>   Auth_OpenID_RAND_SOURCE has been defined as null.
>
> **Data storage**
>
> No SQL database support was found in this PHP installation. See the
>   PHP manual if you need to use an SQL database. The library supports
>   the MySQL, PostgreSQL, and SQLite database engines, as well as
>   filesystem-based storage. In addition, PEAR DB is required to use
>   databases.
>
> If you are using a filesystem-based store or SQLite, be aware that
>   open_basedir is in effect. This means that your data will have to be
>   stored in one of the following locations:
>
> '' If you are using the filesystem store, your data directory must be
>   readable and writable by the PHP process and not available over the
>   Web.
>
> **HTTP Fetching**
>
> This PHP installation has support for libcurl. Good.
>
> **Fetching URL failed!**
>
> Your PHP installation appears to support SSL, so it will be able to
>   process HTTPS identity URLs and server URLs.
>
> **XML Support**
>
> XML parsing support is present using the Auth_Yadis_dom interface.
>
> **Query Corruption**
>
> Your web server does not corrupt queries. Good.

Answer (score 0):

This error has been thrown because SSL verification fail when curl_getinfo on `Auth_Yadis_ParanoidHTTPFetcher`. To solve this issue, you should disable SSL verification by adding this option:

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

to `Auth/Yadis/ParanoidHTTPFetcher.php` at line 93 (after `$c = curl_init();`);

Hope this help.